# Cannot run Java from IE as Standard User

Tags: windows-xp, java, internet-explorer-8

When installing Java 6 update 23 using my admin account i cannot seem to get Java applets to work on IE8 using my standard account. If i run the browser as an administrator Java applets will run in IE8.

This is not a problem using Firefox as both standard or admin.

If i install Java using my standard account which i give admin access for the install. If i than remove admin access from that account and relogin to the computer i can still launch java applets now fine within IE8.

What could be causing the problem with using a seperate account to install the JRE that IE8 isnt liking?

OS: Windows XP Sp2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it's a permission issue on the standard account. Did you check the browser settings and compare it between admin and standard account?